# How to check the SSH login status of routers in bash script with password prompts

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I am running a task where i need to check the SSH login status on 400 remote routers. I have made scripts using expect in bash which SSH the remote routers and run some commands over it. However, there are some routers that are not responding to SSH. I am using if statement to avoid those routers which are failing on SSH. Sample code to check the status on remote router works only if we have password less entry or the private key saved. Could you please help how can I check the SSH status on the remote routers?

If I get the password prompt while doing SSH to the router, I can say that the server is able to SSH the router. There is no need to supply password to it.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=7 username@IP exit
echo $?
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  # Do stuff here if example.com SSH is down
  echo "Can not connect to the device"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,
If you are using `expect` package then there is timeout option there as well.

Else your shell code above is correct way of doing it except just a few corrections:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=7 username@IP date
ret=$?
echo $ret
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]
then
  # Do stuff here if example.com SSH is down
  echo "Can not connect to the device"
fi
```

You can see, we are assigning `$?` immediately to a var. If you don't, then `$?` will contain the return value of `echo $?` command which will be always 0. Hence giving you true for all ssh.
Also I suggest to run some other command rather than `exit` with ssh.

Hope this helps

===Edited====>>>

well since you don't have passwordless ssh enabled. You can try to `telnet` to port 22, if 22 port is open then it will show connected and if its not open then it won't you can grep on it.
Here is the modified code: (Provided that ssh is running on 22 port otherwise change the port in code.)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "" | telnet $IP 22 | grep "Connected"
ret=$?
echo $ret
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]
then
  # Do stuff here if example.com SSH is down
  echo "Can not connect to the device"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Tarique. I should not be using "BatchMode=yes" here, as I do not have password-less login enabled. it is giving me 255 exit status. What I want is to simply run the command "ssh username@IP", system will return the password prompt. If it is returning the password prompt that means SSH is enabled on remote router.

Comment: Your script won't get the password promt, rather it will be directed towards the console.  So it's better that you use expect with timeouts.

Comment: Still wondering how to use it? What logic shall I use which should say that SSH is working on remote router as exit status is giving error 255 even after getting the password prompt?

Comment: well i always use telnet to check for open port. i updated my answer to use telnet. try it out.